# command is not running from php script using shell_exec() or system() or exec() functions

Tags: php, shellexecute

I am working on Windows server and able to run command from command prompt

```
c:> %convertxls% {some args....}
```

But when I run same command from php script

```
*shell_exec(%convertxls% ..... 2>&1);*
```

it gives me error as

**%convertxls% is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

I think when I am running command from command prompt, it run for user which logged in. And when I run the php script it run for "www" user for which path is not set.

Can anybody tell me where I am doing mistake?

*Note: I haven't written complete command.

Comment: Is that literally what you pass to `shell_exec`?

Answer (score 1):

Supply the full path to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

ignacio right,I wanted to add one more point that ignacio did not specify .

Check the parameter disable_functions in the php.ini .

maybe this function is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the environment variable `%convertxls%` is not set.

You can use [`putenv()`](http://www.php.net/putenv) to set it; alternatively, as Ignacio already says, specify the full path.

Comment: Thanks I have set convertxls using putenv() and its working correctly. But when I am using full path its not working and gives error 
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Any ways My work is done thanks once again.

Comment: @Kamlesh You need to set the path in quotes.  `"C:\Program Files\..."`

Comment: note you might want to use single quotes not double quotes as using doubles means the backslash will be used a delimiter and lead to confusing errors